# Alternate way to calculate an integral

Tags: electromagnetism, integration

There's an infinite wire carrying current I on the origin along the z-axis. The question was to calculate $\int$B$\cdot$dl along the path PQ. I managed to get the correct answer by direct integration, but the solution said an equivalent path was to take the integral along the circle (RQ) and then subtract the integral along line(PR, which is zero). So why should this be true?

[image]

Comment: Consider decomposing $\vec{\mathrm{d}\ell}$ into $x$ and $y$ components, and stare at it for a while.  That might help.

Comment: I'm thinking your last PQ should be a PR.

Comment: @R.W.Bird yes, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strong hint: use the relation $\oint\vec B\cdot d\vec\ell \propto I_\text{enclosed}$ to compute the integral on the closed loop $PQRP$.  You've already done all of the segments.

Comment: this one and the comment by @garyp helped a lot. Thanks everyone:)